# jQuery: Prevent wrap() from creating a copy of the wrapping element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery's docs for `wrap()` is the following:

> A **copy** of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements.

This means that when I save the element that I want to wrap around another element into a variable, after wrapping, the variable doesn't point to the wrapping element anymore. So e.g. adding another CSS class to it after wrapping doesn't happen to the wrapping element (which is a copy) but only to the original one.

In contrast to this, `append()` doesn't copy the element.

```
$(document).ready ->
  $appendEl = $("<span href='#'>appended</span>")
  $('#append').append($appendEl) # Append
  $appendEl.addClass 'new-class' # Works

  $wrapEl = $("<span href='#'>wrapped</span>")
  $('#wrap').wrap($wrapEl) # Wrapp
  $wrapEl.addClass 'new-class' # Doesn't work
```

I have created a CodePen to demonstrate this: http://codepen.io/jmuheim/pen/QNQZKw

So why does `wrap()` copy the element, and how can I make the code above work for `wrap()`?

And why does jQuery copy the element when doing `wrap()`? Doesn't this make much overhead and "pollute" things?

Comment: `wrapEl = $('#wrap').wrap($wrapEl).parent()`

Comment: `wrap()` returns element itself. You could just inverse your logic using `$wrapEl.appendTo('#wrap')`

Comment: Wouldn't `append` be the more appropriate method for what you're trying to do?

Comment: @A.Wolff: Thank you, this works better.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: This is only a demo, it doesn't have to make sense.